# MYSQL- Update Row Based on Fields From Another Row In Same Table

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a "matches" table that holds all the matches for various games. It looks like this (team1 and team2 correspond to team ids)

```
team1|team2|tourney_identity|tourney_next|winner
5       6          1              3          6
7       8          2              3          7
0       0          3              5          0
```

Team 0 is "TBD" and is a placeholder when the teams arent decided yet.

I need a query that can run continuously that will grab the winner from a match, then update the match that has the matching identity to tourney_next

It also needs to be able to see if it needs to update team1 or team2

The final table should like this:

```
team1|team2|tourney_identity|tourney_next|winner
 5       6          1              3          6
 7       8          2              3          7
 6       7          3              5          0
```

This is the current subquery I have that isnt working, but is a place to start

```
Update matches as m,(  
  SELECT *, CASE WHEN t1score > t2score THEN team1 ELSE team2 END as winner
  FROM matches
  WHERE isNull(round_id)=false AND tourney_next<>0 AND event_id=$event
  ORDER BY tourney_next) as m2
  SET 
  m.team1= CASE WHEN (m.team1=0 OR isNull(m.team1)=true) AND m.team2!=winner THEN winner ELSE m.team1 END ,
  m.team2= CASE WHEN (m.team1!=0 AND isNull(m.team1)=false) AND m.team1!=winner THEN winner ELSE m.team2 END
  WHERE m.tourney_identity=m2.tourney_next AND m.event_id=m2.event_id
```

Comment: Could you be more specific than "isn't working"?

Comment: You need to specify `m.winner` or `m2.winner` in your `CASE` statements, otherwise you'll get an error because it's ambiguous.

Comment: The `matches` table already contains a `winner` column. In your subquery, you return that column in `*`, and also use `as winner` for the `CASE` statement, so it's returning two columns with the same name. Use a different name for the alias to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: The winner column is only from the subquery. I put in the table picture just to illustrate.

Comment: And currently, when I run it, it will only fill the team1 slot with the first match winner it gets too. Once team1 is filled, nothing else changes